# rename images after batch processing in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab script that converts the images from png to jpeg. However when the new image is produced, it is named : pic.png with the jpeg extension. I want it to be pic with the jpeg extension. 
Here is my script :

```
files = dir('*.png');
for k = 1:numel(files)
   rgb = imread(files(k).name);
   imwrite(rgb,[files(k).name '.jpeg'],'jpeg','Quality',50);
end
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fileparts` to remove the extension:

```
files = dir('*.png');
for k = 1:numel(files)
    rgb = imread(files(k).name);
    [~,f,~] = fileparts(files(k).name)
    imwrite(rgb,[f '.jpeg'],'jpeg','Quality',50);
end
```